Grant permission to cluster resource kafka use sarama library
I have problem granting permissions to kafka confluent resource cluster using sarama. My code is below, when I run it it gives me an error:
error: kafka server: failed to create one or more ACL rules: kafka server: This most likely occurs because of a request being malformed by the client library or the message was sent to an incompatible broker. See the broker logs for more details
When I give permissions to resource topic, group , transactionid, it works fine. It only fails in the resouce cluster. This is my code
func CheckGrant() {
    // struct containing acl for kafka
    tempResource := sarama.Resource{
        ResourceName:        "test9",
        ResourceType:        sarama.AclResourceCluster,
        ResourcePatternType: sarama.AclPatternLiteral,
    }

    // Creating struct final contain acl for kafka
    Acl := sarama.Acl{
        PermissionType: sarama.AclPermissionAllow,
        Host:           "*",
        Principal:      "User:test9",
        Operation:      sarama.AclOperationRead,
    }
    fmt.Println(tempResource)
    fmt.Println(Acl)
    // Connect to kafka
    adminclient, err := kafka.AdminKafka(bootstrapServer, saslEnabled, saslUser, saslPassword, saslMechanism, saslProtocol)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create admin client: %v", err)
    }
    defer adminclient.Close()
    err = adminclient.CreateACL(tempResource, Acl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
}

I still haven't found the error, I checked the log in the broker, but nothing is displayed.
